# Remove every other pixel row

Tags: wpf

I'd like to show only every other pixel row of an UIElement (for instance `Image` or `TextBlock`), so every odd **or** every even pixel row should preferably be transparent (show the background) or be of a solid color. Is something like that possible in WPF?

I hope you can understand what I'd like to do.

After googling a lot I think an `OpacityMask` is the way to go, but I couldn't figure out how to create a proper mask programmatically (I'd like to avoid using an external bitmap with every other pixel row painted).

Comment: Would the person downvoting this question please explain why it's got downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set `OpacityMask` with a brush which will make odd/even rows transparent:

```
<VisualBrush x:Key="Blinds" 
             TileMode="Tile" 
             Viewport="0,0,10,2" ViewportUnits="Absolute"
             Viewbox ="0,0,10,2" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Grid Height="2" Width="10">
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.5"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
        </Grid>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>
```

usage (with Border for simplicity):

```
<Border Background="Black" 
        UseLayoutRounding="True"
        OpacityMask="{StaticResource Blinds}" 
        Height="50"/>
```

to make non-transparent lines, place a Border on top of element which should be covered:

```
<Grid>
    <!--element to cover, e.g. Image, here-->

    <Border Background="Black" 
            UseLayoutRounding="True"
            OpacityMask="{StaticResource Blinds}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: That was the push in the right direction I was looking for, thank you!